# Getting started with Ionic framework - unable to install cordova

Tags: cordova, npm, installation

I am a newbie to Hybrid mobile app development.

Started with [this](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

`npm install -g cordova` is giving me errors.

```
C:\Users\global\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── (empty)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "E:\\Programs\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\global\\AppData\\Roam
ing\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.3
npm ERR! path C:\Users\global\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-7
3d70fb8
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\global\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-73d70fb8' -> 'C:\Users\global\AppDat
```

Please help me to resolve this issue and go ahead

Answer (score 1):

I did an uninstall with npm uninstall -g cordova and then did an install and it worked fine

Regards,
Nalini